# "No volume control found" on Elisa Music Player

Tags: kde, music, volume-control, plasma

Moving the volume slider has no effect on volume and it plays at full volume regardless of the slider. Whenever I start Elisa through terminal it shows

`Warning: "No volume control found"`

Moreover, volume can be controlled using the global control without any problem.
I am currently using KDE neon User Edition 5.12 x86_64 .